# I am using Windows 7 (32-bit), is it better for me to start with Ubuntu (32-bit) too?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am using Windows 7 (32-bit), is it better for me to start with Ubuntu (32-bit) too?

I am new to ubuntu. 
If I want to download ubuntu (32-bit).

Thank you.

Comment: Why not 64-bit for everything? Is there a reason you used 32-bit WIndows?

Comment: Hi edwinksl. I am afraid to try 64-bit OS, I am new to 64-bit OS.

Comment: It is the same as 32 Kitty ;-) One thing: you hardware/system needs to support it. Post the details of your system in the question (motherboard details or brand of the machine).

Comment: Thank you edwinksl. How can I find out the details of my PC hardware? and where can I post the PC hardware's details?

Comment: If you've got plenty of RAM (4 GB or more) use 64-bit

Comment: I am sorry, karel. I didn't mean to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I am deleting this post because this post is duplicated.

Comment: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center. I am not allowed to delete this post.

Comment: I have 108 points. If it is below 100, I think I will be banned from asking any questions, right?

Comment: Please forgive my mistakes, I don't want my account to get banned. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu, 64-bit is recommended so that you can use the full capacity of your hardware since heavy work load may hit the 4GB memory barrier if you choose 32-bit.

So if you have more than 4GB of memory on your system and want to take advantage of it, choose 64-bit.

Comment: Thank you again for the quick help, Charles! Can I install MS office or Adobe products on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: For Ubuntu you can use the online version of MS Office or you can use https://www.libreoffice.org (included in Ubuntu) as well as alternatives to Adobe products.